# Set status bar color using Chrome Mobile Apps

Tags: google-chrome-app

I would like to set the status bar to either a block color or transparent, as in the Google Now app.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome Apps on Mobile](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html) leverage [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), and we have decided to include the [cordova statusbar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/statusbar) by default.

We have included the following cordova statusbar plugin `<preference>`'s by default:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

Which basically means that your app content does not overlay the statusbar (content is pushed down, just like on iOS 6), and the default color is black.  This was a good default for chrome apps, but is not the ideal design for iOS 7 look and feel.

Luckily, you can trivially change these values inside the `config.xml` file at the root of your project.  For your specific request, I would change `StatusBarOverlaysWebView` to `true` and change the color to whatever you app background color is, then remember to run `cca prepare`.  You will also need to adjust your application look and feel to not interfere with the statusbar text (i.e. perhaps by adding `padding-top` to the `html` element).

`config.xml` has other preferences that you can change (though you should not change other tags, as those are auto updated).  You can read about the various `<preference>`'s by looking inside the `plugins/` folder for each plugins' `README.md` file which usually does a good job of describing itself, or by researching cordova application development online.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on Android? This plugin seems to suggest the solution only works on iOS?

Comment: This plugin and these settings apply only to iOS7.  However, there is another preference `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` which you can toggle for Android to show/hide the statusbar entirely.  Its perhaps unfortunate that iOS7 uses a different preference name than Android, but full screen is a little different on that platform.

Comment: is there a way to specify these preferences in the manifest.mobile.json so they are initialized in the config.xml like other parameters?

Comment: @infomofo no you cannot, but I've filed https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/393 to discuss how best to manage setting preferences.